# OpenGL errors finding certain libraries

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, terminal

I am learning about OpenGL and am having great difficulty opening a file with openGL. This is what my reference says to do:

```
"Compile and run the program

To compile the sample program, you need to link to the OpenGL and freeglut libraries. You will also need the GLEW library to be able to use many OpenGL functions, including shaders.

The exact names of these libraries vary from system to system, for example:

Linux
: libGL.a, libglut.a
Compile with

g++ main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLE"
```

I have run this code in my linux terminal (I'm using Redhat) and I get a whole bunch of errors about not being able to locate the files

```
[a1649446@ingb24w027 code]$ g++ main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLEW
main.cpp:46:23: error: glm/glm.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp:47:40: error: glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp:48:32: error: glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp:62: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
main.cpp:62: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘cameraMatrix’
main.cpp: In function ‘int setShaderData(const unsigned int&)’:
main.cpp:102: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
main.cpp:102: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘projection’
main.cpp:105: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
main.cpp:105: error: ‘projection’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:109: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
main.cpp:109: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘modelview’
main.cpp: In function ‘void render()’:
main.cpp:187: error: ‘cameraMatrix’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:187: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
main.cpp:200: error: ‘glm’ has not been declared
```

I'm sure the answer is painfully obvious, but I am an OpenGL noob. I have even located all the openGL libraries and copy-pasted them into the folder with my main.cpp and all associated files, to no avail.

Comment: Your C compiler can't find the GLM header files. Make sure that they are installed, or that you include the folder that `glm/` is in via the `-I` directive.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, where would they be located? and what do you mean about the -I directive

Comment: Usually in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`. Make sure you have the developer library installed too (Probably `libglm-dev` on Ubuntu, though it may be slightly different). The `-I` directive instructs GCC to look in the passed folder for include files.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, I just downloaded glm-0.9.4.0 as apparently I need to install this. Does this HAVE to be in the /usr/include section? I don't have permission on the computer to put files here

Comment: From the description on glm website telling 'GLM is a header only C++ mathematics library' - no, you should be able to place it anywhere and add correct `-I` flag to compiler invocation.